# call multi layout for controller in sails.js

Tags: node.js, sails.js

SAILS.JS

I have two forder in controller: admin and public.

I want to edit view.js file in config forder.

1. if controllers file in admin forder, it call a layout: layout-admin
2. if controllers file in public forder, it call a layout: layout-public

   but i don't know do it.

please support for me with this. thank a lot!

Answer (score 3):

You can do what you want, look the doc here : http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/configuration/sails-config-views

The layout attributs can only be a `string` or a `boolean`, there no way actually to define a layout with a function or for an entire controller.

You can make a feature request to sails to see this feature in a next version.

You can specify layout file in your controller like this :

```
myAction : function (req, res)
{
    var layout = "layout-public";
    if(req.session.authenticated)
    {
            layout = "layout-admin";
    }
    res.view("myview", {
        layout   : layout
    });
}
```

Comment: i know it. but with each res.view() we have to insert layout.

I want edit file view.js in config forder.

Layout: Layout,

Become:

--> if controller is admin forder: Layout: Layout-admin

--> if controller is user forder: Layout: Layout-user

Comment: Sorry but that's not possible (as I know) see my answer.